# How does convert.ToString(C0) behave?

Tags: c#, .net

I have different scenarios. I need output where the value must return comma separated  values in ₹ format which it does in my system where I have the ₹ rupee symbol. Whereas in the user system C0 returns $ value with comma separated values I do not know if he has ₹ symbol in his system or not. Can anyone advise.

PS. I have use the expression in the subject line where I cannot use more functions. I have used convert.ToString("C0").

Comment: my guess is his system does not have ₹ sybmol hence $ is taken by default.

Comment: C0 getting culture info from your computer. You can change your globalization in your apps [like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) or maybe you can hard-coded in your code behind `CultureInfo India = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN");
            Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C0", India));` (but it's not recommended)

Comment: Can you please clarify your code? Is `convert` a variable? What is the data type? Or do you mean the `Convert.ToString` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can brute force search the string for any currency symbols and change them to whatever character you want eg:

```
string s = "$";
foreach (var c in s)
{
    var category = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c);

    if (category == UnicodeCategory.CurrencySymbol)
    {
        //Force convert the char to what every character you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course that works if the desired currency symbol is in the same position as the `$`. If `$` is a prefix and the desired symbol is a suffix, then, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the thread's current UI culture somewhere in your application, then use it when you need to output the correct currency symbol.  For example:

```
double amount = 101.12;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C0", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture));
```

If the issue happens to be a question about whether the culture exists on the running computer, this code can help:

```
bool cultureExists = false;
try
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("hi-IN");
    cultureExists = true;
}
catch
{
    // nothing here
}
```

If you find that it doesn't exist, you'd have to then create it (assuming you have permissions on the machine sufficient for creating the culture). Here's a link that may help with this, if you need it: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/988807/Net-custom-Culture-with-use-case